# How to split a hex string into std::vector?

Tags: c++, stl, hex, std, stdvector

Given a hex `std::string` like `"09e1c5f70a65ac519458e7e53f36"`, how can I split it in chunks of two digits and store them into an `std::vector<uint8_t>`?

I loop over the string in steps of the chunk size, but I don't know how to convert the hex chunk into a number. This is what I have so far.

```
vector<byte> vectorify(string input, int chunk = 2)
{
    vector<uint8_t> result;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < input.length(); i += chunk)
    {
        int hex = input.substr(i, chunk);
        // ...
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: @MatsPetersson I added that to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>

int main(void)
{
    std::string in("09e1c5f70a65ac519458e7e53f36");
    size_t len = in.length();
    std::vector<uint8_t> out;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
        std::istringstream strm(in.substr(i, 2));
        uint8_t x;
        strm >> std::hex >> x;
        out.push_back(x);
    }
    // "out" contains the solution
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For any reason, the compiler says that `>>` is not defined for operand of type `std::io_base` which referres to the `std::hex` I guess. I included iomanip header.

Comment: As I said, I do already include that header. `No operator ">>" matches these operands. Operand types are: std::ostringstream >> std::ios_base &__cdecl (std::ios_base &_Iosbase)`.

Comment: @danijar I used `std::istringstream` instead of `std::ostringstream`. It's _i_, not _o_.

Comment: It works now. I had to use `int` as type for `x` and convert that before back pushing to the vector. Otherwise, the string stream thinks I want to read a single char and not a number.

Answer (score 6):

It's a one liner :-)

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/algorithm/hex.hpp>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    std::string in("09e1c5f70a65ac519458e7e53f36");
    std::vector<uint8_t> out;
    boost::algorithm::unhex(in.begin(), in.end(), std::back_inserter(out));
    return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

two lines are enough,

```
    char str[]="09e1c5f70a65ac519458e7e53f36";
    std::vector<uint8_t> fifth (str, str+ sizeof(str) / sizeof(uint8_t) );
```

Comment: That would give me the ASCII codes for the string. Instead I would like the string characters to be interpreted as hex digits.