# Convert std::string to uint16_t*

Tags: c++

I have serialized some data into an ostream to be send over a devicefile., in binary format.

I am getting output like this when printing the contents of ostream which is fine.

Now I need to calculate the checksum using a certain algorithm :

Since I am using filestreams , I have the binary data in string format :

eg :

46774101101140410MyMakeMyModel10000....

I would like to compute checksum using the algorithm ..

which goes like

The checksum is calculated by 2's compliment addition of all 16 bit words

In case of odd no of octets the final octet assumed as 16 bit 0s padded in MSB .

I am looking into solutions please suggest a fool proof method input is a string or a char *

Thanks

Comment: This code has undefined behaviour. If the input string starts add an odd address, executing this may very well raise a hardware exception.

Comment: hello kerrek , please dont review the code , i meant i need to do a similar checksum calculation, but i dont have a uint16_t* instead a ostream

Answer (score 4):

Your code induces undefined behavior by breaking the strict aliasing rule. If you can't be sure that the data `data` is pointing to is properly aligned for `uint16_t` then this might even become a practical problem (as mentioned in the comments by Kerrek).

For `string` you will have to copy the contents into a `uint16_t`-array and work from there.
It might look something like this:

```
std::string str;
// Put some data into str

std::vector<std::uint16_t> array((str.size() + sizeof(std::uint16_t) - 1) / sizeof std::uint16_t);
std::copy_n(str.data(), str.size(), reinterpret_cast<char*>(&array[0]));

// Work with array
```

Comment: A curious note is that your code depends on `make_unique` initializing the array (which it does), otherwise you might end up reading from an uninitialized variable eventually.

Comment: (Though I'm not actually sure if its allowed to overwrite parts of an object representation at all.)

Comment: This code snippet alone would make me move to a different language. That is not pretty

Comment: @davbryn Moving to a different language is always a good idea if you're dealing with C++.

Comment: @KerrekSB I am aware that the last byte would be potentially uninitialized. Anyway, as I forgot why I chose `unique_ptr` in the first place, I changed it to `vector`.

Comment: @KerrekSB Yes, it is.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your main struggle here is with converting an `std::string` to integers.
You can break your string to chunks of whatever size you need using `std::string::substr`, and convert each chunk to an integer.

Possibly the code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21365515/44673) can show the approach.