# Parsing a long hex string into individual bytes and store it in std::vector<unit_8>

Tags: c++, string, vector, hex

Iam trying to split a long hex string into individual bytes and store it in an integer vector using a CPP program. For example, my input string will like `09e1c5f70a65ac519458e7e53f36` and my expected output will be like `09 e1 c5 f7....`. But I am getting output like `0 e c f.....`. I am getting only half of the byte value. And I already referred this link for reference ([https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21365364/how-to-split-a-hex-string-into-stdvector ]) and I want to get the output without using boost library.

So, I tried the below code as mentioned in the above link.

Here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>

int main(void)
{
    std::string in("09e1c5f70a65ac519458e7e53f36");
    size_t len = in.length();
    std::vector<uint8_t> out;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
        std::istringstream strm(in.substr(i, 2));
        uint8_t x;

        strm >> std::hex >> x;
        out.push_back(x);

    }
    for (int i=0; i<out.size(); ++i)
    std::cout << out[i] << ' ';

    return 0;
}
```

my expected output will be like std::vector<uint8_t> out = {09,e1,c5,f7,0a,65,ac,51,94,58,e7,e5,3f,36}

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30606613/4688321

Comment: On all systems I know that have 8-bit bytes, the `uint8_t` (as well as `int8_t`) is just an alias for the corresponding *character* type. In your case `uint8_t` is an alias for `unsigned char`. And all streams have special overloading for `>>` (and `<<` for output) to read (or display) any character-based type as a character, not an integer. Use plain `unsigned` for generic unsigned integer data.

Comment: @kiner_shah i even tried that also but i am getting only half of the value as answer like 09e1c5f7. since the input hex string is too long i cant able to convert the whole hex string.

Comment: Also take care if your input happens to be an odd number of characters. Your code doesn't handle the last lone digit in that case. Perhaps add validation that the input is always an even number of characters. And validation that all characters are hexadecimal digits.

Comment: Use `uint16_t` instead of `uint8_t`. And then when printing, use this: `std::cout << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << std::hex << static_cast<int>(out[i]) << ' ';`. See [this](https://godbolt.org/z/oETW9Ghdv).

Comment: BTW, you can use `std::byte` instead of `uint8_t` also but it depends on your use case.

Comment: Just off the top of my head, `std::string two_char = in.substr(i, 2); uint8_t x = std::stoi(two_char, 0, 16);` ought to do what you're after. (Yes, GASP, I used `0` for a null pointer...)

Comment: @pete Beker i tried to implement your idea, but it is stored as string instead of hex value. say for example if i try to parse this hex string 48656c6c6f20576f726c64 as per your suggestion and stored the converted value in std::vector<unit_8>. If i try to print values in this vector i got HELLO WORLD as answer instead of 48 65 6c.......

Comment: `std::cout << static_cast<unsigned>(x) << '\n';`. Or just `std::cout << +x << '\n';`. It's the output that's confusing things here, because `char` types are treated as characters (formally, code points) rather than numeric values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement

```
strm >> std::hex >> x;
```

reads only one character.

You could declare the varable `x` as having for example the type `uint16_t`

```
    uint16_t x;

    strm >> std::hex >> x;
    out.push_back(x);
```

And to output elements of the vector you could write

```
std::cout << std::setfill( '0' ) << std::setw( 2 ) << std::hex << ( uint16_t )out[i] << ' ';
```

Answer (score 1):

In C++23, you could do it as follows:

```cpp
#include <ranges>

std::string in("09e1c5f70a65ac519458e7e53f36");

auto view = in
    | std::views::transform([](char c) {
        // map ASCII characters onto hex digit values
        return c >= '0' && c <= '9' ? c - '0' : 10 + c - 'a';
    })
    | std::views::adjacent_transform<2>([](unsigned char hi, unsigned char lo) {
        // combine two digits into a single hex number
        return hi << 4 | lo;
});

// note: you might not even need the vector and could work with the view directly

std::vector<std::uint8_t> bytes(std::from_range, view);
// if std::from_range is not support yet:
std::vector<std::uint8_t> bytes(view.begin(), view.end());
```

*See [live example at Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/4xqcKojqz)*

For older solutions, check out [Converting a hex string to a byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17261798/5740428).

Comment: Works even with EBCDIC (as a-f happens to be contiguous). `auto s = "0123456789abcdef"; return std::distance(s, ranges::find(s, c));` would be portable (requires bound checking though).

Comment: @Jarod42 `0..9` and `a..f` are part of the basic character set. They're guaranteed to be contiguous by the standard, and the current solution is O(1) while a linear search with `std::find` would be O(n). (strictly speaking O(1) because `n` is constant, but still)

Comment: From [does-c-and-c-guarantee-the-ascii-of-a-f-and-a-f-characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29381067/does-c-and-c-guarantee-the-ascii-of-a-f-and-a-f-characters), no such guarantees.

Comment: @Jarod42 this question is just a case of obsolete information on Stack Overflow, as is often the case. `a..f` are part of the [basic character set](https://eel.is/c++draft/lex.charset#def:character_set,basic) and their code points are standardized. C++ files are standardized to consist of unicode code points, so you're guaranteed this behavior. You're right that in [C++11, the character set didn't standardize code points](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/lex.charset#character_set) but this has changed and all answers in your linked Q&A are out-of-date.

Comment: You mean C++ no longer support EBCDIC?

Comment: @Jarod42 that depends on what you mean by support. You can dump whatever you want into a `std::string` but the character literals `'a..z'` are standardized to have a specific numeric value. The only way my code would fail is if you intentionally put non-ASCII data into the `std::string`, but that would be one's own fault, and the data should be re-encoded before being stored in a `std::string`.

Comment: With EBCDIC, `'z'-'a' != 25`. `'a' != 97`.

Comment: @Jarod42 yes, but it is guaranteed that `'z'` is not encoded as EBCDIC. The underlying `std::string` might be, but that would be a design issue that we can't reasonably worry about. There is an infinite set of encodings that could break our code. We are guaranteed ASCII character literals for everything in the *basic character set*, and we can assume that `std::string` is ASCII-compatible.

Comment: Actually I think I am wrong. The character set is well-defined in terms of unicode now, but the encoding of ordinary literals is still implementation-defined (https://eel.is/c++draft/lex.charset#9)